# CakePhp issue: Class 'Login' not found

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm moving my app from codeigniter to cakephp. I have my first issue and I am not able to fix it...

In my controller FeedController, I'm calling this: `Login::isLoggedInUser()`

I have in model folder, the file login.php with this code:

```
<?php

App::uses('Login', 'AppModel');

class Login extends AppModel {

    public function __construct() {
        session_start();

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function authenticateUser() {
        $_SESSION['username'] = 'feeds.123';

        return $_SESSION['username'];
    }

    public static function isLoggedInUser() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] == 'feeds.123') {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't see what's wrong, my error is:

```
Error: Class 'Login' not found  
File: D:\wamp\www\app\Controller\FeedController.php 
Line: 12
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Reading the documentation would have made this question so unnecessary: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of things that a wrong with the code you posted:

1. App::uses should be of the format `App::uses('ClassName', 'Package');`  AppModel is not a package; it is a class.  Packages pretty much just correspond to what folder to look in.
2. You should be using the built-in Auth component for logging in, not writing your own logic.  See the Auth tutorial:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html
3. You should never be calling session_start or accessing $_SESSION directly.  There are features in the framework for that sort of thing, so you should use them.
4. You should avoid accessing session in your models.  That logic should be in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....... Put the code top of your FeedController 
public $uses = array('Login')
**Like this:**
class FeedController extends AppController {
public $uses = array('Login');

}

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
```